# Is there a list of Russian holidays?

Tags: variables, calendar

I want to add Russian holidays to variable `holiday-local-holidays` formatted like:

```el
((holiday-fixed 1 1 "New Year's Day")
 (holiday-float 1 1 3 "Martin Luther King Day"))
```

Is there any list I can use or do I need to start from scratch?

Comment: This is not built-in.  I don't read Russian, but this looks kind of like what you want (hopefully it doesn't say anything that will get me into trouble and will not start a war):  `(setq other-holidays '((holiday-fixed 4 12 "день космонавтики") (holiday-fixed 1 27 "годовщина снятия блокады Ленинграда") (holiday-fixed 9 01 "день Знаний") ))`  Do some Google searching for **russian "holiday-fixed" emacs** and you'll find some more examples.  Try also Google searching **russian "holiday-float" emacs**

Comment: https://github.com/abo-abo/ukrainian-holidays should do most of what you what, unless you really need "годовщина снятия блокады Ленинграда"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just made the package `russian-holidays` because of lack of this info for Emacs. The package reflects the current state of official holidays in Russian Federation. It also includes optional dates for regional holidays in republics of Russia. Data based mostly on Wikipedia articles.

https://github.com/grafov/russian-holidays

There are some official holidays in Russian regions use dates counted as offsets from Orthodox Easter like for example Радоница ("Radonitsa") as 9th day after Easter or based on dates of Islamic lunar calendar like Курбан-Байрам (Eid al-Adha). So for Emacs you will need use functions from `lunar` package and something for evaluating offsets for Orthodox Easter. For the Easter there are functions in my package mentioned above (I took them from https://github.com/abo-abo/ukrainian-holidays).

You can find the mostly full list of Russian holidays in the article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_holidays_in_Russia. Russian translation  of this article has (not complete) list of official holidays in Russian regions.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any list I can use or do I need to start from scratch?

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_holidays_in_Russia) has a list; there's also a short list [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_holidays_in_the_Soviet_Union). You may have to scrape those dates off an HTML table.

Comment: Setting some of the holidays requires certain computations because the dates change, e.g., `holiday-float`, Thanksgiving, court holidays (that are never a Saturday or Sunday).  I think the original poster was hoping to avoid calculating them (reinventing the wheel so to speak) for anything that is not a straight `holiday-fixed`.

Comment: The original poster asked for a ready made list. The first link I provided is one such example where the computations are done for the current year. At the bottom of that page are links to calculations if one needs to start from scratch.